# How to integrate apple map in Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I am new in Apple Watch development and want to integrate apple map in Apple Watch in which just want to show my current location but every time i load the interface in simulator i got the screen like below. any help can be appreciate.

[image]

```
   -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
    {
        CLLocation* loc = [locations lastObject];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D myLocationCoordinate2D = loc.coordinate;
        [self.demoMap setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocationCoordinate2D, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0,0.0))];//set map region
        [self.demoMap addAnnotation:myLocationCoordinate2D withPinColor:WKInterfaceMapPinColorGreen];// set pin on map
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }

#pragma mark - CLLocation Manager

-(void)startTrackingCurrentLcoation:(BOOL)forTrip
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ Start tracking current location", self);
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


    }
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
    {
        NSString *message = @"To use background location you must turn on 'Always' in the Location Services Settings";
        NSLog(@"%@",message);
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
    else
    {
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, @Chirag can you please add code so that i can help you...

Comment: Either 1) add even more code (where does the location manager get started etc) or 2) add some log output that shows which values are passed into this function and how often it is called.

Comment: location manager is not my essential part but my main thing is map is not display any thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this link    https://trymakedo.wordpress.com/tag/wkinterfacemap/.

Check weather you getting current location coordinate that you pass to region.Test by giving predefined coordinate..

Comment: Very help full link @Elalgo van

Comment: in that link only one mistake is there , is that there is no **setMapRect** method but actual method is **setVisibleMapRect**

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it myself and there are MANY pitfalls in this.

I hacked a demo project which you can find here:
https://github.com/sticksen/WatchKit-Map-Sample-Project

Checklist:

- Be sure to request authorization for Location Services and start updating location **after** the user has granted access.
- If authorization is already granted, you can start updating locations right away

And now the worst part:

- Your main target´s (which isn´t the WatchKit target, just to make it clear!) Info.plist has to have a key with the name `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`(depending on what authorization you request) which as the value has a description string why you want to use Location Services. Without setting this key in the Info.plist **it won´t work**!

Comment: thanks for your answer but in your demo i have face same problem. My essential part is display location on map it continues display above screen in your demo. Even i pass static location.

Comment: Sorry, but I don´t quite understand all of your sentence. What does 'it continues display above screen' mean? Can you take a screenshot of it?  Additionally, I assume you have Xcode Version 6.2 (6C131e).

Comment: Furthermore, you have to accept the authorization request for Location Services on the phone simulator (not on the watch simulator), so have a look on that. Did you do that, does the dialog pop up? Try resetting the simulator 'Reset Content and Settings' and do it all again.

Comment: i try your demo too but i see same screen in InterfaceController